# How do I pass a parameter to express.js Router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here's a modified example from Express.js's [routing guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page');
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.send('About birds');
});

...
app.use('/birds', router);
app.use('/fish', router);
```

This prints "About birds" when I visit both `/birds/about` and `/fish/about`.

How do I pass a parameter or something to the router so, in the controller functions, it can tell those two different routes apart?

For example, I'd like to see "Birds can fly" when visiting `/birds/about` and "Fish can swim" when visiting `/fish/about`.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass some "configuration object" so the mini-app does not need to know about all possible routes it may be mounted at (in pseudocode):

```
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
      res.send(magic_configuration.about_text);
    });
   ....
   magically_set_config(router, {about_text: "Bears eat fish"})
   app.use('/bears', router);
```

Comment: router.ge('/birds/about',...) for example?

Comment: @DavidHaim: I've got a group of a few related routes (a "mini-app"). I'd like to be able to reuse them without duplicating, otherwise, if I add another route I'll have to replicate the change for both `/birds` and `/fish`, which is quite error-prone

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with: I pass the "mini-app configuration" by assigning it to `req`:

```
app.use('/birds', function (req, res, next) {
    req.animal_config = {
        name: 'Bird',
        says: 'chirp'
    };
    next();
}, animal_router);

app.use('/cats', function (req, res, next) {
    req.animal_config = {
        name: 'Cat',
        says: 'meow'
    }
    next();        
}, animal_router);
```

and then in my route I can access them:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

...

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  var animal = req.animal_config;
  res.send(animal.name + ' says ' + animal.says);
});
```

This approach allows to easily mount the "mini-app" at another location providing different configuration, without modifying the code of the app:

```
app.use('/bears', function (req, res, next) {
    req.animal_config = {
        name: 'Bear',
        says: 'rawr'
    };
    next();
}, animal_router);
```

Comment: name it like it is: a micro middleware :) Very efficient to pass e.g. a database connection to route handlers that are not worth the overhead of MVC

Comment: @flaschbier Sorry for resurrecting this. I'm debating whether to do the micro-middleware way or just set my values as env variables (set by the process and not global to the machine). Env will make my code cleaner but I've never been a fan of using them. Any suggestion between these two approaches? It will only be used to pass strings (or JSON as strings). I understand that anything more than that will not work since env can only be strings.

Comment: @Felipe – cloud infrastructures use environment to orchestrate services. Hence, I see nothing bad in use of environment _to inject global parameters_ to the application. However, it should not be abused to pass information around between different parts of an application (breaking the software structure), but when it's external configuration that will, by design, not change within the lifetime of a server process, there is nothing bad to inject it via environment.

Answer (score 17):

You're basically talking about injecting configuration to a router.

I have faced with similar problem and figured out that in theory you can export not a router itself, but rather function that accepts configuration and returns created and configured router.

So in your case calling code will look like:

```
var animal_router = require('./animal_router')

app.use('/birds', animal_router({
    name: 'Bird',
    says: 'chirp'
}));

app.use('/cats', animal_router({
    name: 'Cat',
    says: 'meow'
}));
```

While `./animal_router.js` might look following:

```
var express = require('express');

// Create wrapper function that will adjust router based on provided configuration
var wrapper = function (animal_config) {
    var router = express.Router();
    
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
        var animal = animal_config;
        res.send(animal.name + ' says ' + animal.says);
    });

    return router;
}

module.exports = wrapper;
```

Answer (score 10):

So, if you want to serve changes by url, then you can inject params like this:

```
router.get('/:animal/about', function(req, res) {
    // here we have bird or fish in req.params.animal
    if(req.params.animal == 'bird') {
        res.send('Birds can fly');
    } else if(req.params.animal == 'fish') {
        res.send('Fish can swim');
    } else {
        res.send('Unknown animal');
    }
});
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of that but it would also match `/dinosaurs/about`. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: You could simply invoke `next()` in the unknown animal case. That way any other matching routes will get a chance to be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [req.baseUrl](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) to figure that out.

Answer (score -1):

You can add route params like so:

```
router.get('/about/:param1/:param2', function(req, res) {
 //then you can call this handler  through /about/1/sometext get these params from request object:
  console.log(req.params.param1, req.params.param2); // 1, 'sometext'
  res.send('About birds');
});
```

Or you can send parameters through query params:

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
 //then you can call this handler  through /about?param1=1&param2=sometext get these params from request object as well:
  console.log(req.query.param1, req.query.param2); // 1, 'sometext'
  res.send('About birds');
});
```