# How to expose/export a nested function to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**`setupProcess.js`**

```
const setupProcess = (websocket) => {
    let state = 'idle'
    
    const startProcess = () => {
        state = 'running'

        websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            // do something with data
        }
    }

    const stopProcess = () => {
        state = 'idle'
        websocket.onmessage = null
    }
}

module.exports = setupProcess
```

As soon as my app starts, this module is initialized with the websocket.

**`app.js`**

```
const setupProcess = require('./setupProcess')
const router = require('./router')

const ws = require('ws')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
connectDatabase(mongoDbUrl)
app.use(router)

const ws = new WebSocket('wss//test-websocket.com/ws')
setupProcess(ws) // initialized

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`)
})
```

I need to expose the `startProcess` and `stopProcess` methods within `setupProcess` to the router so that the user can start or stop the process once it has been initialized within `app.js`.

**`router.js`**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = new express.Router()

router.post('/process/start', async(req, res) => {
    // should be able to startProcess() from here
})

router.post('/process/start', async(req, res) => {
    // should be able to stopProcess from here
})

module.exports(router)
```

How can I change my design to achieve this? The only thing I can think of is to make `Process` into class of its own and that way, it will be easy to call methods within it. Would appreciate any solutions, thank you!

Comment: Using a class really does seem like the best solution here. You've already noted it, is there a reason why you want a different way?

Comment: @CaptainPerformance Thanks for the reply. The reason I was hesitant to use a class is because, there is only one instance of the process running at any point in time since currently I am the only user of this application. Do you still recommend using a class?

Comment: It makes sense as a design decision here. Another option would be to have a plain function which instantiates the socket and returns an object with the start and stop functions. (probably makes a bit more sense to create the socket in `setupProcess` instead of in the `app`, since it doesn't seem to be used elsewhere). The class or function will only be used once, but I think that's OK since it'll be a good way to organize data with methods.

Comment: Well I put that in `app.js` for simplicity and display here. In reality, `app.js` is calling another function `connectWebsocket()` which defines other websocket methods like `onerror`, which then passes the websocket to `setupProcess`. I think I will have to put it into a class on second thought and it will allow extensibility later on as well. Thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark you as the answer but I will be using a class on second thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a object from inside the parent function.

```js
const setupProcess = (websocket) => {
    let state = 'idle'
    
    const startProcess = () => {
        state = 'running'

        websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            // do something with data
        }
    }

    const stopProcess = () => {
        state = 'idle'
        websocket.onmessage = null
    }
    
    return {
      startProcess,
      stopPorcess
    }
    
}

module.exports = setupProcess
```

Then you can access it like that:

```js
const setupProcess = require('./setupProcess')
const router = require('./router')

const ws = require('ws')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
connectDatabase(mongoDbUrl)

const ws = new WebSocket('wss//test-websocket.com/ws')
const methods = setupProcess(ws) // initialized

app.use(router(methods))



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`)
})
```

router.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = new express.Router()

module.exports = (methods) => {


    router.post('/process/start', async (req, res) => {
        // should be able to startProcess() from here
        //methods.startProcess();
    })

    router.post('/process/start', async (req, res) => {
        // should be able to stopProcess from here
        //methods.stopProcess();
    })

    // return the router
    // so express can use it
    return router;

}
```

Comment: Marking you as the answer since this answered the direct question I posed. However, in reality as @CaptainPerformance suggested I will go with my original decision to use class (as this seems to be best practise).

Comment: Hey just wanted to update that this solution unfortunately does not work since Express gives an error saying `TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function` when you structure the router into an anonymous function. Have to unmark this. Please let me know if you are able to modify this so that express will accept it. I am currently using https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234851/3796268 as a temporary solution (which is not nearly as pretty) as what you suggested.

Comment: Ahh, i forget to return the router from the function, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap router module into a function for expose methods:

```
const express = require('express');

// require('./router')
// module.exports = 
const router = ({startProcess, stopProcess}) => {
    const router = new express.Router();
    
    router.post('/process/start', async(req, res) => {
        // should be able to startProcess() from here
    });

    router.post('/process/start', async(req, res) => {
        // should be able to stopProcess from here
    });
    return router;
}


// require('./setupProcess')
// module.exports = 
const setupProcess = (websocket) => {
    let state = 'idle'
    const startProcess = () => {
        state = 'running'
        websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            // do something with data
        }
    }

    const stopProcess = () => {
        state = 'idle'
        websocket.onmessage = null
    }
    return {startProcess, stopProcess};
}


const ws = require('ws')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
connectDatabase(mongoDbUrl)

const ws = new WebSocket('wss//test-websocket.com/ws')
const methods = setupProcess(ws) // initialized


app.use(router(methods))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`))
```