# How to handle file upload using express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here are my server-side index.js:

```
import Express from 'express';
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';
import http from 'http';
import TestRouter from "./TestRouter.js";
let app = new Express();
let httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(Express.json());
app.use(fileUpload({debug:true}));

app.post('/test/uploadFile',async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    Object.keys(req.files).forEach(key=>{
        console.log("Name:"+req.files[key].name);
        console.log("MIMETYPE:"+req.files[key].mimetype);
        console.log("File size:"+req.files[key].size);
        console.log("==================================");
    });
    res.status(200).end();
});
let portNo=8080;
httpServer.listen(portNo, () => {
    console.log('Express server is running on localhost:'+portNo);
})
```

It works fine.
When I change the code to :

```
import Express from 'express';
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';
import http from 'http';
import TestRouter from "./TestRouter.js";
let app = new Express();
let httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(Express.json());
app.use(fileUpload({debug:true}));
app.use('/test', TestRouter);
let portNo=8080;
httpServer.listen(portNo, () => {
    console.log('Express server is running on localhost:'+portNo);
})
```

And the TestRouter.js source code is below:

```
import Express from 'express';
let wrapper = function () {
    const router = Express.Router();
    router.post('/:action', async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.params.action);
        switch (req.params.action) {
            case "uploadFile":
                console.log("hi");
                res.status(200).end();
                break
            default:
                next();
                break
        }
    });
    return router;
}
export default wrapper;
```

I find that the TestRouter does not be triggered.
Why?

Comment: What's the wrapper for? Did you intend to _call_ TestRouter instead of passing it?

Comment: I just copied it from the internet. Is it a proper express router code?

Comment: It's important to take the time to understand the code you are copy pasting. If I were you I would take a look at what the `.use()` function expects an argument. Learn your tools.

Comment: In my old application, I need to pass a parameter to the router, so I follow the below post to create a router. It works fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232258/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-express-js-router

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get it working by replacing the following statement:

```
app.use('/test', TestRouter);
```

with

```
app.use('/test', TestRouter());
```