# middleware to pass parameters is not working?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I am implementing the accepted solution to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232258/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-express-js-router) in order to pass parameters to my routes.

However, I am noticing that while the parameters seem to be set in my app.use, the parameters are not being passed to my router file.
For example,
in server.js

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const fooRouter= require('./routes/foo');
const stringVar = 'some string';

app.use('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  req.params = {
      connect: stringVar,
  };
  console.log(req.params); // is printing the correct value
  next();
}, fooRouter);
```

but in routes/foo.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const parameters = req.params;
  console.log(req.params); // prints an empty object -> parameters.connect is undefined
  console.log("string: ", parameters.connect);
}

module.exports = router;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That are two different routes. Why do you exepct that a request made to `/` has `req.params.connect` set when its only set in requests made to `/foo`?

Comment: I was under the impression that the "/" route in foo.js is "/foo". And a route like "/bar" in foo.js would be "/foo/bar". Is this not correct?
To be clear, I am using the GET request at "localhost:3000/foo".

Comment: Post your full code. Its unclear what is where defined under which variables names. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have edited my code to be more clear. The code is pretty much the same. Hope that helps!

Comment: `req.params` is scoped to its handler function. Instead of using `req.params`, use something else like `req.defaults`. `req.params` is a fresh object for every path handler function, and can not be overriden from a middleware function.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my issue! How do I accept your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, `req.params` is scoped to its handler function and can not be overridend from a middleware function.

Use something else instead of `req.params`, like `req.defaults`:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const fooRouter = express.Router();

fooRouter.use(function (req, res, next) {

    req.defaults = {
        connect: "some string"
    }

    next();

});

fooRouter.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const parameters = req.defaults;
    console.log(req.defaults);
    console.log("string: ", parameters.connect);
});

app.use('/foo', fooRouter);



app.listen(8123, (err) => {
    console.log("Listening" || err);
})
```

```
Listening
{ connect: 'some string' }
string:  some string
```

Tested with curl: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8123/foo`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `bodyParser` to parse the from data since the latest version it comes with builtin express middleware

```js
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const fooRouter= require('./routes/foo');
const stringVar = 'some string';

app.use('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  req.someting = {
    connect: stringVar,
  };
  console.log(req.someting ); // is printing the correct value
  next();
}, fooRouter)
```

If you want to store the data on the request object and want to access in the next route handler you can store on the `req` object itself as you here I'm storing the something object on the request object

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.something); 
}

module.exports = router;
```

Remember we don't store anything you want in the reqeust object we usually store the the data in req the `auth` middleware so that in the controller we don't have the fetch the user from the db

eg: `jwt payload, User via passport, role`